# Eloquent query to select values from many to many relationship using laravel

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I'm working on a project that have a many to many relationship between 2 tables the first table is the cities table and the second one is the checkpoints table..

The city have many checkpoints and the checkpoints may belong to many cities..

So far I have created a new table called checkpoint_city contain the checkpoint_id and the city_id..

So city A have chickpoints X,Y BUT city B have X,Z

Now I want to select the only checkpoints that belongs to city A and B together which is X..

My code until now is :

```
 $checkpoints = CheckPoint::select('*')->where('type', 'n')->where('checkpoints.active', 1);

        if(! empty($request->city_ids)) {
            $cities=explode(",",$request->city_ids);

            $checkpoints = $checkpoints->crossJoin('checkpoint_city','checkpoints.id','=','checkpoint_city.checkpoint');
            $checkpoints = $checkpoints->crossJoin('cities','cities.id','=','checkpoint_city.city')->whereIn("cities.id",$cities);

            for($i=0; $i<count($cities); $i++){
                $checkpoints = $checkpoints->where("cities.id",$cities[$i]);
            }

           $checkpoints = $checkpoints->groupBy('checkpoints.id');
        }
```

But that didn't work for me, any help?

Comment: And how does your SQL attempt look?

Comment: what do you mean by SQL attempt?

Comment: You say you want an SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use laravel `whereHas`, which check relationship exist with extra condition

```
$checkpoints = CheckPoint::where('type', 'n')
                    ->where('active', 1)
                    ->whereHas('cites', function($query){
                        $query->where('name','A');
                    })->whereHas('cites', function($query){
                        $query->where('name','B');
                    })->get();
```

Assuming you have `belongsToMany` relation with name `cites` in your `CheckPoint` model and `City` has `name` field